Cannot restore a USB stick to its normal state (gpated shows less memory than it is)
In gparted, my 16 Gb USB stick is seen as a 512 bytes disk at /dev/sdh. How to revert it to the normal state?
All suggestions I found refer to running fdisk on /dev/sdh and deleting the partition, which doesn't work for me because the partition at /dev/sdh is already empty; the problem is that it's only 512 bytes. The g and n commands fail as well.
└─$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdh 
Disk /dev/sdh: 512 B, 512 bytes, 1 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb243aea2

└─$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdh1
Disk /dev/sdh1: 15.11 GiB, 16228941824 bytes, 31697152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E06254CB-CECA-45B3-93EE-7564CC5D020E

Initially, I ran dd with if of=/dev/sdh pointing to a 4gb iso file and it failed with a message "No space left" resulting in a 3gb /dev/sdh. Then I ran another command suggested else that supposedly should override the first sector and hence reset the USB stick to its original state. But instead it reduced the /dev/sdh to 512 bytes.
Some other commands I tried:
└─$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdh1
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Exact type match not found for type code 7200; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'
Exact type match not found for type code 6500; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'
Exact type match not found for type code 7900; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'
Exact type match not found for type code 0D00; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
3774212538 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Disk /dev/sdh1: 31697152 sectors, 15.1 GiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 0E14995A-79F2-4139-B7C3-ECA64C344CE2
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 31697118
Partitions will be aligned on 1-sector boundaries
Total free space is 31697085 sectors (15.1 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1       778135908      1919645538   544.3 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   2       168689522      2104717761   923.2 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   3      1869881465      3805909656   923.2 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   4      2885681152      2885736650   27.1 MiB    8300  Linux filesystem
                                                                           


Adding a few more details if it helps.
$ lsblk
sdh      8:112  1  15.1G  0 disk 
└─sdh1   8:113  1  15.1G  0 part 

└─$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdh1

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.39.3).                                        
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.          
Be careful before using the write command.

The device contains 'vfat' signature and it will be removed by a write command. See fdisk(8) man page and --wipe option for more details.                 

Command (m for help): g

Created a new GPT disklabel (GUID: E06254CB-CECA-45B3-93EE-7564CC5D020E).
The device contains 'vfat' signature and it will be removed by a write command. See fdisk(8) man page and --wipe option for more details.                 

Command (m for help): w

The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Re-reading the partition table failed.: Invalid argument
                                                                             
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or partx(8).



When I try deleting the "Partition 1" in the Disks app, I got the following error message:

Failed to delete partition '1' on device '/dev/sdh': Invalid argument (udisks-error-quark, 0)


Solved by running
sudo wipefs --all --force /dev/sdh

as described at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-wipefs-to-wipe-a-signature-from-disk-on-linux/
and reinserting the stick.
